# Firestore emulator | FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection()... | RPC_ERROR HTTP error has no status

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When i make a query to my firestore database i got this error

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Apparenly i havent pass the right argument to `getFirestore()`

Here is my db initialization code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "@firebase/firestore/lite";

class Db {
static firebaseApp = null;

constructor() {
    if (!Db.firebaseApp) {
        Db.firebaseApp = initializeApp({
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
        });

        const useEmulator = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
        this.db = getFirestore();
        if (useEmulator) {
            const emulatorHost = "192.168.1.51";
            const emulatorPort = 8080;
            connectFirestoreEmulator(this.db, emulatorHost, emulatorPort);
        }
     }
   }
 }

export default Db;
```

the static property is for executing initializeApp one time at the instantation of the class and not getting this error:

> FirebaseError: Firestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only modify settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.

Here is the queries i make:

```
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from "@firebase/firestore/lite";
    import Db from "./DataBase.js";

class SignUpClientSide extends Db {
    async checkUsernameUniqueness(username) {
        const usersRef = collection(this.db, "users");
        console.log(usersRef);
        const lowercaseQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(query(usersRef, where("username", "==", username.toLowerCase())));
        console.log(lowercaseQuerySnapshot);
        const uppercaseQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(query(usersRef, where("username", "==", username.toUpperCase())));

        if (!lowercaseQuerySnapshot.empty || !uppercaseQuerySnapshot.empty) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issues by specifying the android gateway address (10.0.2.2) and not the localhost nor the local IP of the host

```
if (useEmulator) {
  const emulatorHost = "10.0.2.2";
  const emulatorPort = 8080;
  connectFirestoreEmulator(getFirestore(), emulatorHost, emulatorPort);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `SignUpClientSide`, `this.db` is likely undefined because you haven't called the parent's constructor.

In Javascript you can use the `super()` method to call the parent constructor, likely in your own constructor (ie. `SignUpClientSide.constructor`), but this isn't done automatically.

See this example to learn more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: I tried to call the db class constructor but in this case i don t need the constructor. I can use props of the herited class just like that

Answer (score 0):

I just update the constructor by moving `this.db = getFirestore();` out of the if statement and use directly the firestore intance

```
constructor() {
    if (!Db.firebaseApp) {
        console.log("hit");
        Db.firebaseApp = initializeApp({
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: ""
        });
        const useEmulator = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
        if (useEmulator) {
            const emulatorHost = "127.0.0.1";
            const emulatorPort = 8080;
            connectFirestoreEmulator(getFirestore(), emulatorHost, emulatorPort);
        }
    }
    this.db = getFirestore();
}
```

Now i'am able to make a query request to the db but i got this new error:

```
[2023-07-12T07:28:04.118Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.23.0_lite): RPC_ERROR HTTP error has no status
```

I thinks it s a network error. The firestore emulator is on